# not able to get image path from model class

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, model

[please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzhag.png) I think It seems to be confusing to ..but ill tell you what is the problem...I was having a recycler view to display image but what was my problem was I only want the image above 1000 likes should be displayed in recycler view ...I tried to implement and I later my friend told me  that recycler view was purely ui..it cannot be done inside the recycler view ..so I created a interface which holds **listviewholder** like this and 2 model class **implementing the listviewmodel**

```
   interface ListViewModel {
    int VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO = 1;
    int VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    int getViewType();

}
```

**PhotoViewModel**

```
class PhotoViewModel implements ListViewModel {
String imagePath;
String date_created;
String description;


public PhotoViewModel(String imagePath, String date_created, String description) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.date_created = date_created;
    this.description = description;
}
public PhotoViewModel(){}

@Override
public int getViewType() {
    return VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO;
}

}
```

**VideoViewModel**

```
class VideoViewModel implements ListViewModel{

String image_path;

public VideoViewModel(String image_path) {
    this.image_path = image_path;
}
@Override
public int getViewType() {
    return VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO;
}
}
```

in the post fragment where I get image and other thing mainly where recycler in located in  ..

```
   List<Photo> photos = mPhotos;
                List<ListViewModel> listViewModels = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Photo photo : photos) {
                    if(photo.getPopularlist().contains("true")){
                        if(photo.getType_post().equals("Photo")){
                       //I thought this code will pass the photo.imagepath and description  
listViewModels.add(new PhotoViewModel(photo.getImage_path(),photo.getDescription(),photo.getDate_created()));[please look at this image][1]



                        }
                        if(photo.getType_post().equals("Video")){
                            listViewModels.add(new VideoViewModel(photo.getImage_path()));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

here comes the issue I am able to get body but not the image ..when log that it shows null ..I think the image path is not passed ..I thought

in adapter

```
 PhotoViewModel photoViewModel = new PhotoViewModel();
 imageLoader.displayImage(photoViewModel.imagePath,imageview);
```

**I used this code to get image path ...it does not work ...does any one know how to solve this ...when I log it shows null**

**this is my model class**

```
 public class Photo  implements Parcelable{

 private String description;

private String image_path;
private String photo_id;
private String user_id;
private String tags;
private List<Likes> likes;
private String popularlist;
private List<Comment> comments;
private String links;
private String type_post;
private String date_created;
private String category;

 protected Photo(Parcel in) {
    description = in.readString();
    image_path = in.readString();
    photo_id = in.readString();
    user_id = in.readString();
    tags = in.readString();
    popularlist = in.readString();
    links = in.readString();
    type_post = in.readString();
    date_created = in.readString();
    category = in.readString();
}

 public static final Creator<Photo> CREATOR = new Creator<Photo>() {
    @Override
    public Photo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Photo(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Photo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Photo[size];
    }
};

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getImage_path() {
    return image_path;
}

public void setImage_path(String image_path) {
    this.image_path = image_path;
}

public String getPhoto_id() {
    return photo_id;
}

public void setPhoto_id(String photo_id) {
    this.photo_id = photo_id;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(String tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public List<Likes> getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public void setLikes(List<Likes> likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}


public String getPopularlist() {
    return popularlist;
}

public void setPopularlist(String popularlist) {
    this.popularlist = popularlist;
}

public List<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public String getLinks() {
    return links;
}

public void setLinks(String links) {
    this.links = links;
}

public String getType_post() {
    return type_post;
}

public void setType_post(String type_post) {
    this.type_post = type_post;
}

public String getDate_created() {
    return date_created;
}

public void setDate_created(String date_created) {
    this.date_created = date_created;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Photo() {

}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(image_path);
    dest.writeString(photo_id);
    dest.writeString(user_id);
    dest.writeString(tags);
    dest.writeString(popularlist);
    dest.writeString(links);
    dest.writeString(type_post);
    dest.writeString(date_created);
    dest.writeString(category);
}

public Photo(String description, String image_path, String photo_id, String user_id, String tags, List<Likes> likes, String popularlist, List<Comment> comments, String links, String type_post, String date_created, String category) {
    this.description = description;
    this.image_path = image_path;
    this.photo_id = photo_id;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.likes = likes;
    this.popularlist = popularlist;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.links = links;
    this.type_post = type_post;
    this.date_created = date_created;
    this.category = category;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Photo{" +
            "description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", image_path='" + image_path + '\'' +
            ", photo_id='" + photo_id + '\'' +
            ", user_id='" + user_id + '\'' +
            ", tags='" + tags + '\'' +
            ", likes=" + likes +

            ", popularlist='" + popularlist + '\'' +
            ", comments=" + comments +
            ", links='" + links + '\'' +
            ", type_post='" + type_post + '\'' +
            ", date_created='" + date_created + '\'' +
            ", category='" + category + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Comment: How do you get the image from firebase?

Comment: Please also add your database structure.

Comment: okk ...please wait

Comment: you can see in post fragment...4 line code I get ..image path from firebase

Comment: please check this guys..I have updated my code...please help me guys ....

Comment: Does `if(photo.getType_post().equals("Photo")){` return true?

Comment: Yes does return true

Comment: Also it display the body in recycler view.. Except the image

Comment: Only thing is i am not able to get image path